# Заголовок с линией

Tags: css

Подскажите, как сделать заголовок, под которым линия по центру на всю ширину экрана, как на рисунке ниже? Под самим заголовком линии не должно быть видно.
И фон под заголовком с линией может быть разного цвета 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например с помощью псевдоэлементами `:before` и `:after`:

```css
h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333;
  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

h3:before,
h3:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bbb;
  top: 50%;
}

h3:before{
  left: -9999px;
  right: 100%;
}

h3:after{
  left: 100%;
  right: -9999px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<h3>Новинки</h3>
</div>
```